# A word for "to make more concrete" in philosophical context?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a verb for *to make more concrete*. Initially, I chose *to practialize* but it is not an English term according to ispell. Please, come up with verbs of the same meaning.

**Example**

The situation where I want to use this is in philosophy. The sentence is like this

> XYZ philosophical ideas are meant to make THX issues more practical over long-term but solving the practical problems requires in the first step critical understanding of present state through certain philosophical machinery.

The reason I want to avoid the term *practical* is that it has a bit of a diverted meaning in this context — the goal is to make abstract ideas to help other people, not necessarily physical things but to transform technical issues into practical.

Even the term *practical* is a bit diverted here. I am writing a synopsis about a very long philosophical article where the author redefines or moulds the original meaning of *practice* into *reasoning*, *judging* and *perception*.

Clearly I want to avoid this term because it means something altogether different to normal. I need to find another way to describe the original author's desire for *to make things more practical*, not by repetitively using *practical*, but some variety to this process with words having different connotations and background.

Initially, I thought that I would favor scientific terms such as *precipitate* from Chemistry because of the technical background in my course but I am now unsure, it may make the text too hard to read.

Comment: Why not use "make more concrete"?

Comment: @JasperLoy: `'to make more practical'`, I need to find a term to make theoretical/etc things more practical or even physical i.e. to materialize/recipitate -- now I need terms to describe this practicalization deeper. I am looking for verbs.

Comment: @dowvoter: leave some reason please.

Comment: Solidify? Develop? Consolidate? Streamline? Condense? Concentrate? Clarify? You might wish to start by doing the latter.

Comment: Here are some suggestions: 'concretize', 'realize', 'reify' (a lot of technical meaning in philosophy), 'specify', 'instantiate'. Are those in the direction you're looking for?

Comment: @Mitch: yes I think so but I have weak philosophical background into the reification and what does the term actually mean? Is it easily abused?

Comment: @Mitch: yes that is, with fallacies outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_(fallacy)#Similar_fallacies), I can come up with much more specific way of reasoning about the repetitive arguments. Thank you.

Comment: ***reify*** is one of my hate-words, because you can’t stem it down to an English root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the phrase *make more concrete* is perfectly acceptable. You shouldn't worry too much about repetition if the word or phrase is correct in the context.

But since you're looking for more options:

- > [**Crystallise**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Crystallise) - make free from confusion or ambiguity; make clear; — The Free Dictionary
- **Make (more) tangible** where *tangible* means *able to be touched*.
- > [**Elucidate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Elucidate) - to make clear or plain, especially by explanation; clarify. — The Free Dictionary
- > [**Materialise**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/materialise) - come into being; become reality. — The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 10):

Also consider *[reify](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reify)*, "to regard something abstract as if it were a concrete material thing", with synonyms *conceptualize, concretize, objectify, picture.*  Related term
*[reification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reification)* means "consideration of an abstract thing as if it were concrete, or of an inanimate object as if it were living".  From these definitions one sees that *reify* and *reification* refer not to making something concrete, but instead to regarding it as if it were, which in your philosophical context may be suitable.

*Edit 1.* I wrote "consider *reify*" above, rather than "use *reify*", due to not finding meaning in the example sentence, hence not knowing what part of speech to suggest.  The comment "Objectify fits nicely" suggests to me that *objective* [which is analogous to *pragmatic*, from another answer] may be relevant.  Perhaps the example means something along the lines of

> Applying X philosophical ideas to reify Y issues makes these issues subject to objective scrutiny, but also requires philosophical machinery Z to do A to B.

*Edit 2.* From etymonline, *[reify](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=reify)* has a Latin stem, *re*, with English suffix *-ify* attached; if you require pure English, substitute *thingify* for *reify*.  The etymology of *reification* makes more interesting reading.  From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=reification&searchmode=none) and [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reification), respectively, we have:

> 1846, "act of materializing," from L. *re-*, stem of *res* "thing" + *-fication*. In Marxist jargon, translating Ger. *Verdinglichung*.
>
> c. 1846 Macaronic calque translation of German *Verdinglichung*, using *-ification* (“making”) for *ver*- + Latin *res* (“thing”) for *Dinglichung* (“thingliness”)

Answer (score 2):

The usual direction is to abstract, theorize, or generalize. You want to go back from those abstractions to something more concrete and tangible. I suggest:

- concretize (to make more concrete)
- reify (to make more 'real')
- realize (similar etymology to 'reify' but less formal. more about an 'awakening' in one's own thoughts)
- specify (to give specifics)
- instantiate (to set some variables)

Comment: *Reify* is not my favorite word. :(

Comment: I agree it's not the best and would not be my first choice, but it does fit.

Answer (score 2):

I think OP is making a rod for his own back by focussing on the metaphorical use of *concrete* (and all associated words making the distinction between abstract concepts and "solid" physical reality).

The issue in hand is primarily the contrast between *theoretical* and *practical* - but as stated, OP doesn't want to use the obvious word "practical". I therefore suggest [pragmatic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pragmatic) *- of or pertaining to a practical point of view or practical considerations.* Or even just **useful**.

I realise the question title asks for "a word" meaning *"make more concrete"*. But his example sentence would be fine simply replacing *"practical"* with *"pragmatic/useful"*. Though I personally would go for the simplicity of **...make THX issues more relevant to everyday life** or similar.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand by your quote is:

> Philosophy strives to illuminate real world issues but has to start by
>   discussing abstract principles.

You really have to jiggle the whole sentence to get anything halfways readable.

Answer (score 1):

## Short & Sweet

Please don’t use *reify* or *reification*. They're
prominent in postmodernist criticism, which is just a bunch of hooey.
They're academic jargon.  You can’t apply straight English derivational
morphology — simple stemmming — to figure out what they mean.  They
force you to know Latin.  It's really irritating.

Better one-word answers include *to express* and *to embody*. Those are hard-working verbs without a bunch of faked-up *-ificationalizing* endings. Those don’t require massive pretence the way *reify* does. I don’t see what is wrong with *to make concrete* — is there saw law forbidding two-word answers?

Comment: This sounds like a rant rather than an answer. Can you edit radically to leave just the part that is your suggested answer?

Comment: @Mitch I’ve tried. Whether that’s good enough for what you want, I don’t know.  Just saying not to use *reify* when plain English will do seems  abrupt, as though it no longer seeks to convince but to dictate, so I’ve left my longer exposition as an appendix to the main answer.

Comment: +1, bringing you back to love. Whether the word "reification" is needed gives rise for example to a page-and-a-half-long footnote in "Cognition and Eros: A Critique of the Kantian Paradigm." (http://books.google.com/books?id=EaZSy24J0WoC, footnote 6 page 218). A word that needs justification like that shouldn't be used without a page-and-a-half footnote about why it's needed. I run across the word now and then and feel its creeping into popular use; to me it makes the writer sound like a thesaurus rummager wanting to sound authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

> to make more concrete

is to convert from the abstract and useless to the concrete and practical. or as you say,

> to transform technical issues into practical.

This really is a description of

> **to apply**

In your example this would read as:

> XYZ philosophical ideas are meant to **apply** to THX over the long-term...

Answer (score 0):

Consider [flesh out](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=flesh%20out).

> [flesh out](https://sites.google.com/site/missfeldersclass/Home/teaching-philosophy): to come up with the details once a guideline has been given

"*XYZ philosophical ideas are meant to flesh out THX issues over long term, but solving the practical problems requires in the first step critical understanding of present state through certain philosophical machinery*."