# Is there a name for this literary device?

Tags: writing, figures-of-speech, figurative

Is there a term that describes the act of giving tangible qualities to an intangible noun?

> I **stumbled over** a metaphor

or

> I felt sadness **condense** on my skin

The first one might just be "figure of speech", but perhaps there is a more specific name.

Comment: I guess it is the good old *metaphor*, only robed in verbal form.

Comment: Anything that is not literal is called 'figurative' or a 'figure of speech'. So both are figures of speech. Which particular one for each is up to judgement. I don't know if there is such a label specifically for a concrete thing replacing an abstract idea. Here's a good collection of some of them: [Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/)

Comment: Indeed, it is metaphor, which is just another term for "figure of speech", "simile", or "metonymy". All of these terms and many more are referring to the same cognitive phenomenon. Take a look at Lakoff and Johnson.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A word for "to make more concrete" in philosophical context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/a-word-for-to-make-more-concrete-in-philosophical-context)

Answer (score 2):

reification: essentially making something intangible (or abstract), tangible

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reify?q=Reify)
> Reify:
> to make something more real or consider it as real:

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence to demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

The closest word I could find was *personification* which means:

> [personification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification) — the attribution of human form or other characteristics to anything other than a human being.

Its synonym is *anthropomorphism*.

The key difference between the word you seek and *personification* is that you are not strictly describing *human* characteristics. *Personification* isn't strictly human in nature but it does typically refer to characteristics that are related to active beings or people. More strictly:

- Describing a non-human with human terms (e.g. the dog pondered its existence thoughtfully)
- Describing an inanimate object with animate terms (e.g. the sun smiled down on us)

But what you want is a term that refers to an intangible object as if it were tangible. This is very similar to *personification* and I was able to find a few descriptions of *personification* that included such usage. An example:

> One of the primary uses of personification is in metaphor, **in which something tangible is used to represent something intangible**. By personifying the intangible, it takes on a sort of life in the mind of a reader or listener. A person might describe a bad experience as a nightmare, or like a roller coaster ride. A storm could be described as an angry child throwing a tantrum, yelling and screaming and throwing things about. Death is often personified as the grim reaper, a frightening robed figure carrying a scythe whose job is taking the souls of the dead to the afterlife. — [wiseGEEK](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-the-different-uses-of-personification.htm)

Dictionary definitions do not seem to support this usage but until a more appropriate word enters the English lexicon it is the closest match.

Aside from that, the more generic term would be *metaphor*:

> [metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) — a figure of speech that describes a subject by asserting that it is, on some point of comparison, the same as another otherwise unrelated object.

Comment: Hmm. The Grim Reaper is personification (death is turned into a person); but *nightmare* and *roller coaster* are simply metaphor, surely?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: The internets seem to be somewhat divided on this. As the answer notes, dictionaries don't typically include the tangible to intangible variation but I was able to find various sites claiming that it qualifies as personification. I'll add a note about metaphor but I suspect the asker was looking for a more specific term.

Comment: Personification was my first gut reaction to the question as well. Metaphor is probably more correct though.

Answer (score 0):

The word embodiment works well in this case.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Thank you for contributing an answer. As Stack Exchange aims to be a database of *authoritative* answers, please provide some substantiation for your answer (have a look at MrHen's answer). Examples include relevant links (with appropriate citations) and reasoned arguments.