# Word for something that represents, but is not, something abstract

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

A while ago I heard a word that means something representing something abstract, but not actually being that thing. It was in the context of Java's Class objects - that classes in Java are loaded into the JVM in a special way, but that Class objects exist to represent those; they're _____. I feel like it started with an R? Thanks!

Comment: This may be better suited to a site dealing with computer terms. (It may not.)

Comment: representative?

Comment: It was less common than that

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Do you mean 'Instances' of that particular class?

Comment: No, not instances of a class, the objects that represent the class itself, as in Foo.class

Comment: You'll likely have more luck in programmers.SE.

Comment: I'd be open to a moderator migrating it

Comment: Mostly that sounds like a symbol, but if it was obscure and started with an R, maybe reification?

Comment: Oh yes! Reification!

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58697/2085).

Comment: Since you says it starts with R, References come to mind. But I doubt that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [**reification**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reification). From Cambridge Dictionary:

> **reification**
> *noun* [ U ] /ˌriː.ɪ.fɪˈkeɪ.ʃən/ /ˌriː.ɪ.fɪˈkeɪ.ʃən/ formal ​
>
> **the act of changing something abstract (= existing as a thought or idea) into something real:**
> *the reification of fantasies*

This standard definition is very slightly different from an existing object that stands in for something that remains abstract (that sounds a bit more like a [symbol](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/symbol)), but I can see it being used that way in a specialized context. I've mostly heard it used in the social sciences, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Reification_(computer_science)&oldid=713271172) says that in computer science

> **Reification** is the process by which an abstract idea about a computer program is turned into an explicit data model or other object
> created in a programming language. A computable/addressable object — a
> resource — is created in a system as a proxy for a non
> computable/addressable object.

That second sentence, especially, sounds like what you've described.